# Php check if unlink returns false or true

Tags: php, permissions, return, unlink

I want to check wether unlink returns true or false.

Currently I tried this:

```
if(!unlink("$directory/$file"))
{
     echo "works not";
}
else
{
     echo "works";
}
```

I get not output, I just get this message:

```
unlink("path"...VTS_01_1.VOB): Permission denied
```

But it does not work, any ideas?

Comment: And what you got here as output?

Comment: I got nothing, I just get this message: `unlink("path"...VTS_01_1.VOB): Permission denied`

Comment: I intentionally have that folder/file open to catch the error and show a suitable message to this issue, there is no permission error in that case it just shows me the error because I have the folder/file opened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP unlink() handling the exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318230/php-unlink-handling-the-exception)

Comment: Well, something *should* be output here one way or the other… Can you try to do literally *anything else* besides `echo`, to rule out that for whatever bizarre reason there's some issue with outputting to `stdout`? Throw an exception instead, write to some other file, play a sound or something, just to see that it *is* progressing into either `if` or `else`.

Comment: I put an exception into both but I did not get anything

Comment: Not exactly same but you will get some help (bare me if not):- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975998/how-can-you-catch-a-permission-denied-error-when-using-fopen-in-php-without-us

Answer (score 3):

You may use `is_writable` function before trying to `unlink`:

```
if( ! @is_writable( "$directory/$file" ) ) {
     echo "works not";
}
else {
    unlink( "$directory/$file" );
    echo "works";
}
```

> `is_writable` function will show warning (if error is displayed according to configuration) if it fails, so use `@` to suppress the error as shown in the CODE above.

Having said that, **your CODE is not wrong either**, even with your CODE along with the Error, you should've got `works not` as output as well. If you don't get it, that most likely mean in your CODE an error handler is set somewhere & the handler is ending the execution by `exit` or `die`.

For example, the following CODE will only generate Error, no output (if `"$directory/$file"` is not writable):

```
function handle_error( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    die( $errstr );
}
set_error_handler( 'handle_error' );

// Note: since error handler ends execution with die
// even suppressing warning with @unlink will not give you
// any output other than the error
if( ! @unlink( "$directory/$file" ) ) {
     echo "works not";
}
else {
     echo "works";
}
```

So check for either `set_error_handler` or `set_exception_handler`, see if they are stopping the execution. Output buffering may also be the cause.